# Pass props to Layout in NextJs

Tags: next.js, layout, getserversideprops, getstaticprops

```js
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import { Inter } from "@next/font/google";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import Layout from "../layouts/Layout";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="m-5">
        <div className="bg-white h-[400px] flex justify-center items-center text-4xl">
          Welcome to Dashboard
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
Home.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
  return <Layout>{page}</Layout>;
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
  return { props: { title: "HomePage" } };
}
```

I need to pass props from getStaticprops to Layout Component. i tried to pass as props but it doesnt working. Can someone help eith this?

Comment: This seems to be working. You'll get the props in the `Home` component. What's the issue you are facing?

If you are expecting it to come inside the `Layout` component, it won't